find -print0 doesn't work piped to with xargs -0 when -or conditions are used
I'm trying to "grep" content from a list of files in current directory, matching either asp, html and htm extensions.
I am also using cygwin, with:

bash: 4.4.12(3)-release,
findutils (find and xargs): 4.6.0-1

To do so I created a bash function:
function grepinpages() {
  find ./ -type f -iname "*.asp" -or -iname "*.html" -or -iname "*.htm" -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -n200 egrep "${@}" --
}

So that I could:
grepinpages -il "default\.asp"

And get all files containing, case-insensitive, "default.asp".
The problem then is that I only get the match from a few files. In fact, if I change the function to:
function grepinpages() {
  find ./ -type f -iname "*.asp" -or -iname "*.html" -or -iname "*.htm" -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -n200 echo egrep "${@}" --
}

I only get something like
egrep -il default\.asp -- file1.htm file2.htm dir1/file1.htm

Then if I go ahead and simplify it even more:
find ./ -type f -iname "*.asp" -or -iname "*.html" -or -iname "*.htm"

I get all files listed!
If I add -print0 and pipe to something
find ./ -type f -iname "*.asp" -or -iname "*.html" -or -iname "*.htm" -print0 | xargs -0 -n200 echo

Then again I get the "incomplete" list.

Turns out I was not grouping find "or" options in parens. Thus this fixed for me:
function grepinpages() {
  find ./ -type f \( -iname "*.asp" -or -iname "*.html" -or -iname "*.htm" \) -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -n200 egrep "${@}" --
}

As I specified -print0 it related only to -iname "*.htm" and no default action was assumed for the other alternatives, I guess.
